# Recursion for printing out words in sentence backwards

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on getting a method that prints the words of a sentence out backwards. I'm very close to a solution but am hitting a minor snag.

Here is my code:

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {

        if (str.equals(""))
            return "";

        else {

            int i = str.length() - 1;

            while (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
                if (i - 1 < 0)
                    break;
                i--;
            }

            return str.substring(i,str.length()) + reverseString(str.substring(0,i));
        }

    }
```

Now the problem is the that the output from my test:

```
String test = "This is a test.";

System.out.println(reverseString(test));
```

Is giving me this back:

```
  test. a isThis
```

Now, when I try to bump up the index of the substring being returned and add in the spaces manually, it cuts off the "T" in "This". That is, if I decide to instead return as follows:

```
return str.substring(i+1,str.length()) + " " + reverseString(str.substring(0,i));
```

then I get back

```
test. a is his
```

Does anyone have any advice or pointers on my implementation in general?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the return statement to this:

```
return str.substring(i, str.length()).trim() + " " + reverseString(str.substring(0, i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the sentence using String.split and then iterate over the resulting array backwards. To split at whitespace do

```
test.split(" +");
```

The split method takes a Regular Expression and the above means: split at one or more consecutive whitespaces.

Recursive approach:

```
public String reverse(final String s) {

    final int pos = s.indexOf(' ');
    if (pos > -1) {
        return reverse(s.substring(pos + 1).trim()) + " " + s.substring(0, pos).trim();
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I've done an iterative approach. I'm trying to figure out a recursive approach.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon: Sorry, missed that. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this approach you can selectively create substring based on whitespace. For input `This is a test.` below method will give return `test. a is This`. Idea here is if you have a leading space, you will actually convert to trailing space.

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {

        if (str.equals(""))
            return "";

        else {

            int i = str.length() - 1;

            while (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
                if (i - 1 < 0)
                    break;
                i--;
            }
            String substring;

            if(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                substring= str.substring(i+1,str.length())+" ";
            }
            else
            {
                substring= str.substring(i,str.length());
            }

            return substring + reverseString(str.substring(0,i));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Working with your code you would just need to add an additional space in front of whatever string you want to reverse such as with this code

```
reverseString(" " + str)
```

when you first execute the method.

Comment: but that would always be true, in this case... `i` is the length of the last word in the temporary recursive `str`, so it's always less than the length of `str`. what you're suggesting would result in every letter being treated as a separate word (i.e. it would return `. t s e t  a  s i  s i h T `)

Comment: yes you are right, i misunderstood the question i have updated my answer

Comment: This would reverse the sentence as is, instead of reversing words in a sentence. `Original: This is a test. Reversed: .tset a si sihT`